# How to send multiple parameter AJAX in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

How do I send multiple values for AJAX Laravel.
for Example:

```
$('#submit_').on('click', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var form_data = $('#create').serialize();
     var form_taxonomy = 'category';
     $.ajax({
          headers: {
              'X-CSRF-Token': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
          },
                type: 'post',
                url: '{!! URL::route('category') !!}',
                data: {formData:form_data,formTaxonomy: form_taxonomy},
                success: function () {
                    $('#append').load('{!! URL::route('loadCat') !!}');
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    alert(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).category[0]);
                }
            });
            jQuery("#create").val('');
        });
```

controller code:

```
public function create(messageRequest $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()) {
        $name = Input::get('formData');
        $taxonomy = Input::get('formTaxonomy');
        return response()->json($name, $taxonomy);
    }
}
```

html code:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/category" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token"
                                                                                          value="IzByO9fU5yeanaVCudCQpkL5bXGzUh9B4jb400iU"
                                                                                          type="hidden">

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control text-right" id="create" name="category" type="text">
        </div>
        <div id="submit_"><input name="createSub" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" type="submit">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

message request validate:

```
    public function rules()
{
    return array(
    'category'=>'required|alpha|unique:taxonomies,name',
    );
}
public function messages(){
    return [

        'category.required'=>'fill',
        'category.alpha'=>'only charecter',
        'category.unique'=>'dublicate'
    ];
}
```

This code not work . I used my other examples, but no one was not responsive to the problem is that I don't know only parameter data in laravel how to call the amount that would not be faced with an error and stored in the database .

Comment: what do you mean by *This code face value with error*

Comment: Your code looks correct - what errors are you getting?

Comment: an error message to fill in form . **Please fill out the form** . @ImtiazPabel

Comment: This code not work @madalinivascu

Comment: an error message to fill in form @Chris

Comment: Can you paste your form html? Are you sure nothing else is getting in the way? As that sounds like a validation error - perhaps you have frontend validation preventing submission?

Comment: Can you show your messageRequest class?

Comment: edited question @patricus

Comment: added html code to question @Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using FormRequests to act as validation for that controller method. In this case, your FormRequest is: MessageRequest - which includes a validation parameter by the name of `category`.

When your ajax submission takes place, it is not providing the `category` field, and therefore failing validation.

To test, try supplying category data to the ajax data:

```
data: {formData:form_data,formTaxonomy: form_taxonomy, category: 'somevalue-unique-to-your-taxonomies'},
```

Comment: This code to solve the problem for me . But why should use of this ? 
i. e. Every time to be sent to the validate added value ?

Comment: It boils down to your requirements. Is category required for this request?

Comment: i used this code `data: {'formData': form_data,'formTaxonomy': form_taxonomy,'category': form_data},`

Answer (score 3):

You've already serialized the form, which generates the `name=value&name=value` query string format. It looks like you then want to add data to this query string for submission. You will need to do this somewhat manually, but it can be done like this:

```
$('#submit_').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form_data = $('#create').serialize();
    var form_taxonomy = 'category';
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
        },
        type: 'post',
        url: '{!! URL::route('category') !!}',
        // manually combine your form data and your additional post data
        // into one query string
        data: form_data + '&' + $.param({formTaxonomy: form_taxonomy}),
        success: function () {
            $('#append').load('{!! URL::route('loadCat') !!}');
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            alert(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).category[0]);
        }
    });
    jQuery("#create").val('');
});
```

### Edit

With your existing code, the issue that you're having is that your `messageRequest` validation says that the `category` field is required, but your request data does not have a `category` field. Because of this, your validation is failing, and will return a `422` response with a JSON object containing your validation errors.

With the updated code above, your request data now has a `category` field, so validation is passing, but you have some other error in your code that is generating a 500 error. You need to track this down and fix it, which may require another question.

Comment: get error `500 Internal Server Error`  and problem `alert(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).category[0]);` and not set to Database

Comment: Well, you would also need to update the server code you've shown. There will no longer be a `formData` entry, the request would just have all of your form elements in it. I may not be understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am novice, please guide more

Comment: i get `The HTTP status code "0" is not valid.` how to solve?

Comment: @MeysamSaberi In your code, you have this: `return response()->json($name, $taxonomy);`. The second parameter to the `json()` method is supposed to be the status code as an integer, but you've passed in your taxonomy data ("category"), which will be converted to an integer (0). The first parameter should be an array of your data, so your code should actually be: `return response()->json([$name, $taxonomy]);` Additionally, with my code, there is no more `formData` entry in the input, so `$name = Input::get('formData');` should be `$name = Input::get('category');`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your data part like this :

```
data: {'formData':form_data,'formTaxonomy': form_taxonomy},
```